# How to know collision between 2 images javafx

Tags: javafx, collision-detection

how to get the collision of 2 images or Bounds Intersect on javaFx? I move one image but if I touch the second image I want to trigger something.

```
gc.drawImage( img2, 0, 400, 950, 100 );
    gc.drawImage( img3, 200, 200, 150, 50 );

if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT ){
            if(img2.intersects(img3.getBoundsInLocal())){
            doSomething();
        }
}
```

this code doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper for the image, a Sprite class for example, and you can use that wrapper to give it x,y coordinates. You can get the intersection with the help of a Rectangle2D shape.

```
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class Sprite {

    private Image image;
    private double positionX;
    private double positionY;
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public Sprite(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
        width = image.getWidth();
        height = image.getHeight();
        positionX = 0;
        positionY = 0;
    }

    public void setPosition(double x, double y) {
        positionX = x;
        positionY = y;
    }

    public void render(GraphicsContext gc) {
        gc.drawImage(image, positionX, positionY);
    }

    public Rectangle2D getBoundary() {
        return new Rectangle2D(positionX, positionY, width, height);
    }

    public boolean intersects(Sprite spr) {
        return spr.getBoundary().intersects(this.getBoundary());
    }
}
```